# jquery function reloads the page on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem. Below is my code:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#find').on("click",function(){
        name = $('#q_name').text();
        location = $('#q_location').text();
        city = $('#q_city').text();
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

When this anchor tag whose `id` is `find` is clicked the alert "Clicked" appears then the whole page is reloaded. I am getting name, location and city values from `p` tags separately.

Also when I keep only one assignment and discard other two then page reloading stops and only alert occurs. This is the beginning as I have to send this collected data to via AJAX to controller function but first I want to stop reloading the page. What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I'm very new to jQuery and only know few of its basics. Please help.

Comment: Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()` choose either to work.

Comment: are you using a submit instead of button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the page reload and navigation behavior of anchor tag, you can use `javascript:void(0)` or [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="find">Click</a>
```

Or

```
$(function() {  
    $('#find').on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        name = $('#q_name').text();
        location = $('#q_location').text();
        city = $('#q_city').text();
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

Now your page will not reload on click on this anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the default behaviour of the link (ie. changing the URL) by using `event.preventDefault`, try this:

```
$('#find').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    name = $('#q_name').text();
    location = $('#q_location').text();
    city = $('#q_city').text();
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Did you pass event (`e`) object to function (first line)?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `location` variable to `location1`.
i think it refer to browser location.

Comment: Or even better add a var before the location and city assignments.

Answer (score 0):

try this. simple and easy

Modify the href attribute as given below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="whateverFunction()" >
```

Comment: Good practice is to keep all layers separated. Mixing HTML and Javascript is something I would not recommend, get's easily out of hand.